# What mission planner should I be using for INav?

Tags: multirotor, quadcopters, smartphone-app

I'm new to the quadcopter community and am looking to plan my first mission for my drone.

As far as I can tell, the recommended mission planner is an Android app? I am hoping there is a good alternative to this for INav.

I just want to check it can leave the ground with a simple hover at 1m and land?

Comment: Welcome to Drones.SE! If you haven't done so already please take a look at the [tour]. So are you asking if you can download INav on your Android phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official recommended mission planner for INav on the Google Play Store:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eziosoft.ezgui.inav&hl=en

From the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/wiki/iNavFlight-Missions):

> Mission Planner for INAV can be downloaded from the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eziosoft.ezgui.inav&hl=en). There is a free version which limits number of waypoints to 5 and (very reasonably priced) paid-for version with additional functionality. The application is not open source. For questions and help the RCG "Mission Planner for INAV" thread can be used: [RC Groups support forum](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?3030784-Mission-Planner-for-INAV-%28Android%29).

**There used to be an app for iOS as well, but this is no longer available on the app store.**

Another app for Android is Droid Planner 2:

> **Droid Planner 2 can also be downloaded from the [GitHub](https://github.com/DroidPlanner/Tower/releases/download/Droidplanner_v2.8.6_RC2/Droidplanner_v2.8.6_RC2.apk). It is free and released under GNU Public License v3.**
>
> Droid Planner only supports iNav's one-way MAVLink protocol. The following telemetry data is displayed:
>
> - Vehicle position on map, active flight mode, heading, altitude, speed.
> - A broken connection recovers once restored after any amount of time. The flight track remains on screen even when data link is broken -> lost model recovery. Log files can be opened in PC software Mission Planner.

More options can be found in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/iNavFlight/inav/wiki/iNavFlight-Missions).